# Jest TypeError is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jestjs

I am writing tests for a simple call to the star wars api `swapi.dev` just learn on some asynchronous testing.

however, I get the following error `TypeError: swapi.getCharacters is not a function`

Below is my function

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const getCharacters = async (fetch) => {
  try {
    const getRequest = await fetch.get('https://swapi.dev/api/people');
    const data = await getRequest.data;
    return {
      counts: data.count,
      results: data.results,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};

module.exports = getCharacters;
```

and this is my test

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const swapi = require('./script2.js');

it('calls swapi to get star wars characters', () => {
  expect.assertions(2);
  return swapi.getCharacters(fetch).then((data) => {
    expect(data.count).toEqual(82);
    expect(data.results.length).toBeGreaterThan(5);
    expe;
  });
});
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watch *.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You exported your function as default export but you use as named import which is wrong  so as long as you use as default import then it should be working normally.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
module.export = {
  getCharacters : getCharacters
}
```

in your script2.js file.